# Prevent Scala from escaping double quotes in XML unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, xml, scala, escaping

If I generate some Javascript in my Scala code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     foo("{bar}");
</script>
```

and the Javascript contains a double quote character (like in the example), it will appear as `&quot;` when the XML is converted into a string, and Firefox will reject this Javascript as having a syntax error.

How can I avoid this Javascript error, without removing `&quot;`s that *are* actually needed?

I'm using Play framework 1.2.4 with the Scala module 0.9.1, which requires Scala 2.8.1.

Comment: I don't know Scala but would putting the script content in a CDATA block help?

Comment: @Pointy No, unfortunately it makes no difference.

Comment: See [this ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3368).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

would something like this work for you?

```
scala> val bar=scala.xml.Unparsed(""""hello"""")
bar: scala.xml.Unparsed = "hello"

scala> val x = <script type="text/javascript">foo({bar});</script>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <script type="text/javascript">foo("hello");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling it from a Play template, you should be able to do ${myscript.raw()} rather than just ${myscript}. The #{verbatim /} tag should also work.

Comment: I'm afraid the Scala module uses a different, Scala-based templating language - which I'm using - so I can't use this answer.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Bummer that it doesn't include some kind of raw functionality for JS.